# Android comparing String with EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm writing a game which i ask riddles to the player. I've been trying to compare the riddle answer with the input from EditText but I haven't been successful so far. Could anyone help me with that?

```
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String answer = et.getText().toString();
            riddlePlay.setAnswer();
            if (riddlePlay.isTrue(answer)) {
                tr.savePlayerData(tr.getqNum() + 1, 1, getApplicationContext());
                tr.loadPlayerData(getApplicationContext());

                try {
                    tr.readQuestion();
                    tr.readAnswer();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                tv3.setText(tr.getQuestion().substring(1));
            }
        }
    });
```

tr is a TextReader i have written and it works. For save and load methods I use SharedPreferences. Save asks for questionNumber, level and context it should update the question but it doesn't.

Comment: what exactly is riddlePlay and its isTrue method?

Comment: riddle play is a class to play the riddle game and isTrue checks if the given String matches with the answer of the riddle. If it matches it returns true.

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? does it not enter that if (riddlePlay.isTrue(answer))? or is it something else?

Comment: If isTrue then it should increase the questionNumber int in the SharedPreferences, then by loading it I'm updating the qNum int in the tr(TextReader). Then it should read the next question and change the text in the TextView when pressed, but it's not doing it.

Comment: so what does it do? does it enter the if or not?
You should first debug and see exactly the behavior of the app and check at least the more specific part of what is not working since it's not clear just to say "its not doing it".

Comment: @Yonatannir NirI've put some prints in the OnClickListener and it is not entering the if. I did it as Jikiwiki told me below. If it equals then return true else false and it is not case sensitive.

Comment: ok so if it not enters the if, can you edit the question with the isTrue method? It's probably something there

Comment: Ok i have found the problem. When I printed the answer everytime i clicked it says that the answer is in quotation marks fixing it is easy now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if there are quotation marks around the answer in `readAsnwer` method

Answer (score 0):

In *riddlePlay.isTrue(answer)* you should compare it with

```
if (riddle_answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)){
   //Do something
} else {
   //Not matching
};
```

or if it's Case sensitive use

```
if (riddle_answer.equals(answer)){
   //Do something
} else {
   //Not matching
};
```

Comment: Tried it, still not working but thanks for the answer, it could prevent a future bug.